# Prestashop - Display Custom Features in Layered Navigation Block

Tags: filter, prestashop, layered-navigation

I am using **Prestashop version 1.6** and I have some products that have **custom features** values. By default, **Prestashop** doesn't display them in the filter of **Layered Navigation Block** plugin, it only displays the **pre-defined** values in the filter results.

How can I include the custom feature values onto the filter results? Or maybe a way to transfer the custom features in the database to pre-defined values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform your custom values to pre-defined values by setting the field `custom` to 0 in table `feature_value` for the needed values.

Comment: This does the job of transfering the custom features to pre-defined values, but in this manner I have the same Feature multiple times across the filter. Any way of concatenating duplicates?

Comment: You can write a script that will find all duplicates for a value and delete all except one that will be the unique value, and link this value to all products linked to the previously deleted values.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/thirtybees/blocklayered/tree/3c9d655a350c31d589102df97b18d082213e42cf is the Layered Nagivation Module for Thirtybees, a version of Prestashop 1.6.1 . It navigates by any feature when I use it - not just default features - so you may be able to install it on Prestashop 1.6 or compare it with your own files and try to spot the differences.